# how to center inline elements

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is center my title in the middle of the page. It is inline with the search bar and is centering based off of the distance from the edge of the search bar to the other side. How can I make it so it ignores where the search bar is? https://jsfiddle.net/nyvxhb4h/, so in the jsfiddle the nav menu is centered, so the title should be right above it.  Thanks -Kyle

Here is the problem area I think incase jsfiddle link stops working:

```
#head {
    margin: 2% auto 2% auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#head h1 {
    display: inline;
}

<div id="head">
    <h1> Title </h1>
    <form action="test.asp" style="float:right; margin-right: 3%;">
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `form` before the `h1` and update its CSS to `position:absolute; right:0`. https://jsfiddle.net/nyvxhb4h/1/

```
<div id="head">
    <form action="test.asp" style="position:absolute; right:0; margin-right: 3%;">
        <input type="text">
    </form>
    <h1> Title </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: oh i see how absolute positioning works now with the right property, thanks ^.^